# Problem to transform string date-range to two date columns

Tags: python, string, dataframe, date-range

My dataframe column contain a string which corresponds to the daterange. It can be in two different "formats" depending if the end of the range falls on the same month: "Aug 20-24" or in different months: "Aug 30-Sep 3"

I successfully split my From and my To dates but can't find a way to copy the "month" when necessary.

```
trades["From"], trades["To"] = trades["DateRange"].str.split("-", 1).str
trades["FromMonth"], trades["FromDay"] = trades["From"].str.split(" ", 1).str
trades["ToMonth"], trades["ToDay"] = trades["To"].str.split(" ", 1).str
trades["ToDay2"] = trades["ToDay"].copy()
trades["ToDay2"][trades.ToDay.isnull()] = trades["ToMonth"].copy()
trades["ToMonth"][trades.ToDay.isnull()] = trades["FromMonth"].copy()
trades["ToDay"] = trades["ToDay2"]
```

My ToMonth is "empty" when the end falls on the same month as the start.

Comment: Despite the fact that you probably got your answer already, it would be nice to provide code that is actually a working example.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign "ToMonth" to the value for "FromMonth" if it is empty/null like this

```
trades["ToMonth"], trades["ToDay"] = trades["To"].str.split(" ", 1).str
trades["ToMonth"] = trades["ToMonth"] or trades["FromMonth"]
```

`or` returns the first value if it is "truthy" (True, not 0, not empty list, etc.) or it returns the second value

Comment: It return this message: "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()." but thanks for the prompt answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem was coming from my split statement...

To split on space character I used " " which was incorrect.

I replaced my statement with below one and it fixed my problem.

```
trades["FromMonth"], trades["FromDay"] = trades["From"].str.split(None, 1).str
```